# converting mysql query to redbean query

Tags: redbean

Can anyone help me convert this mysql query to redbean query please?

```
SELECT category,sum(price) from transaction GROUP BY category.
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use like

```
$results = R::getAll( 'SELECT category,sum(price) from transaction GROUP BY category' ); 
// $results is multidimensional array
```

Here is reference link: http://www.redbeanphp.com/queries

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert anything. You just write:

```
$transactions = R::get("SELECT category,sum(price) from transaction GROUP BY category");
```

Answer (score 0):

A better conversion would be:

$sql = "SELECT category, sum(price) FROM transaction GROUP BY category";

$transactions = R::getAll($sql);